# Error while using h2o.init() in R

Tags: r, h2o

I get the following error whenever I use `h2o.init()`:

> localh2o<-h2o.init()
>
> H2O is not running yet, starting it now...
> Error in system2(command, "-version", stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE) :
> '""' not found
> In addition: Warning message:
> In .h2o.checkJava() :
> Found JRE at C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/java.exe but H2O requires the JDK to run

I am running it on RStudio Version 0.99.473 and R version 3.2.2, 64 bit os

Comment: Do you have a jdk installed? http://openjdk.java.net/

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory:

> Found JRE at C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/java.exe but H2O requires the JDK to run

You need to install the JDK and point the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the JDK directory (the parent of the bin directory), if it isn't automatically done by the installer.

Comment: But that's the warning message. The actual error message is 
Error in system2(command, "-version", stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE) : '""' not found
How do I solve that?

Comment: So, you're saying that you have a JDK installed and it is properly configured? What do you see if you type `javac -version` in the CMD?

Comment: Thanks! I updated my JDK version as you suggested, and it works now.