# Error when starting h2o.init() in R

Tags: r, h2o

I am getting an error when trying to start h2o. Running the following start-up commands:

```
library(h2o)
localH2O = h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321, startH2O = TRUE)
```

Gives the following error:

```
Error in system2(command, "-version", stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE) : '""' not found
```

It's not particularly enlightning. Does anyone have a hint as to what is the problem? Java is installed on the system, but unlike the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896008/error-while-using-h2o-init-in-r) I do not get any Java warnings.

Running system("java -version") gives:

```
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Here is the output of sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] h2o_3.6.0.8              statmod_1.4.22           deepnet_0.2             
 [4] TTR_0.23-0               selectiveInference_1.1.1 intervals_0.15.1        
 [7] lars_1.2                 glmnet_2.0-2             foreach_1.4.3           
[10] Matrix_1.2-2             wq_0.4.4                 zoo_1.7-12              
[13] skm_1.0.2                stringi_1.0-1            devtools_1.9.1          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.2      rstudioapi_0.3.1 magrittr_1.5     MASS_7.3-43      munsell_0.4.2   
 [6] colorspace_1.2-6 lattice_0.20-33  stringr_1.0.0    plyr_1.8.3       xts_0.9-7       
[11] tools_3.2.2      grid_3.2.2       gtable_0.1.2     iterators_1.0.8  digest_0.6.8    
[16] reshape2_1.4.1   ggplot2_1.0.1    bitops_1.0-6     codetools_0.2-14 RCurl_1.95-4.7  
[21] memoise_0.2.1    scales_0.3.0     jsonlite_0.9.17  proto_0.3-10
```

Comment: Please add your OS, the `sessionInfo()` and the Java version.

Comment: Hi Pascal, my java version is Version 8 Update 65 (build 1.8.0_65-b17). I have attached my sessionInfo() to the original question. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. You not only need to install the java client but also the java SDK software.

See also [logged issue](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-2316) with H2O

Comment: Thanks phiver. That was the problem. It's not really clear in the documentation that the SDK is needed.